# Are open subsets of $R^n$ homeomorphic if all homotopy groups are trivial

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am wondering if the following is true:

> Let $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open sets.  Suppose $\pi_i(U) =\pi_i(V) = {1}$ for all $i = 0,1,2,3, ...$ 
>   Then $U$ and $V$ are homeomorphic.

I came about this question after reading Hatcher's proof that the "house with two rooms" is contractible.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to asking whether $U$ is homeomorphic to the open disk $D^n$.

Answer (score 5):

Open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ are homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes, so by [Whitehead's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem), you're asking whether contractible open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ are homeomorphic to the open $n$-ball $D^n$.

This is not true: the [Whitehead manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) is a contractible open subset of $\Bbb R^3$, not homeomorphic to $D^3$. (Whitehead asked this very same question while trying to prove the Poincaré conjecture, which is why he ran into this particular manifold.)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of Whitehead's theorem to this argument. The Whitehead manifold is already a counterexample before you mention Whitehead's theorem.

Comment: It's not relevant to the argument. I just prefer to replace weak contractibility with contractibility whenever possible, as I find the latter more conceptually reasonable. I mention it only so the OP has a better grasp on the space he's considering.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a positive result in this direction: any open simply connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is homeomorphic to the open disk $D^2$. This is a consequence of the [uniformization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem), and as Mike Miller's answer shows, the corresponding statement with $2$ replaced by $3$ is false.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with this.  However, I do not know if such a thing holds for some other $n$.